# dojo xhrGET not working while the same URL works in a browser

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo

I am trying to display search reults in a Spring MVC 3 app based on the input entered by user in two text boxes. I am using dojo xhrGET request ( and the user input as a couple of request parameters). The intention is to display search results in  a dojogrid based on the value in these boxes.

The request (sample url listed below),

```
http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/subscribers?customerId=091300036&searchBy=ci)
```

works fine when I paste it in a browser address bar. However, when invoked via xhrGET, I dont see any response and it is not contacting the controller.

In FireBug, I see the same request in both cases.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/SampleApp/subscribers?customerId=091300036&searchBy=ci 200 OK
```

However, the response in the successful case (via browser) is a JSON object, whereas in the dojo request case, the response contains my entire jsp source code.

What should I be doing on the xhrGET request. Am I not using the correct dojo events. Since this is a search, I was using GET and not POST. Here is the relvant html and js code.

```
    <input id="customerId" >    
    <input id="searchName" >
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" onclick=search()>
                Search
    </button>   

    dojo.ready(function(){
        var textbox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
            value: "Search By Name or Email",
            onFocus: function(){ 
                var ph = dijit.byId("searchName");
                ph.attr("value",""); },
            placeHolder: "Search By Name or Email"
        }, "searchName");
        textbox.startup();

    });

    dojo.ready(function(){
        var textbox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
            value: "Customer Id",
            onFocus: function(){ 
                var ph = dijit.byId("customerId");
                ph.attr("value",""); },
            placeHolder: "Customer Id"
        }, "customerId");
        textbox.startup();

    });        

    function search() {
        var criteria1 = dijit.byId("customerId").value;
        var criteria2 = dijit.byId("searchName").value;
        dojo.xhrGet({
            // The URL of the request
            url: "/SampleApp/subscribers?customerId=" + criteria1 + "&searchBy=" + criteria2,
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function(newContent) {

            },
            // The error handler
            error: function() {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: interesting part here is not the request side but in turn the response side. For some reason your SampleApp handles the XHR different then a direct. This gives me an idea, that maybe your JSP framework serves the request differently, depending if it has specific headers set? Try to complete the dojo.xhrGet URL as an absolute (`url: 'http://localhost:8080/everything...'`)

Comment: @mschr, Thanks for your response. I tried to use the absolute url and that produced similar results.  When I do the xhrGet, is it supposed to behave exactly as giving the url in a browser.

Comment: @ "is it supposed to behave exactly as giving the url in a browser" i suppose it should, yes - but when it boils down, it is basically a GET request with a set of headers attached to it. A GET request carries nothing else then this (no payload etc).

Comment: Your server reads the headers and can act upon them, MVC often has distinquished actions based upon type of request, i.e. POST / PUT / GET etc. Try adding `headers: { 'User-Agent': navigator.userAgent, 'Referer':document.location.href }` as configuration of the xhrGet call (see http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/xhrGet#example-8-dojo-xhrget-call-with-headers)

Comment: mschr, Thanks. I have not had a chance to try with headers yet, as I am held up with other tasks. Will try and keep you posted. Again, thanks for your time and response.